# In R: how to specify non-adjacent columns in function parameters

Tags: r

```
variable <- some.function(some.datafile, data.col=4:6)
```

How would I designate columns 4 and 6, but not 5?

I have tried c(4,6) and 4,6.

Comment: `c(4, 6)` should do the trick, so if that's not working you'll have to post some more details about what you're doing.

Comment: Aye. Echoing @josilber's statement. Please provide a more reproducible example.

Comment: Question withdrawn.  c(4,6) suddenly and inexplicably worked.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work with `c(4, 6)` and `[]` subsetting. For instance, this works for me:

```
someFunction <- function(x, n) {
  y <- x[n]
  y
}

test <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10),
                   y = rnorm(10),
                   z = rnorm(10))
someFunction(test, 1)
someFunction(test, 1:3)
someFunction(test, c(1, 3))
```